# How to do a joining for making decision from 2 different filter

Tags: informatica

There are total 4 tables invoked in this mapping:  Market,Cost, A, B,

```
Read_sourceTB_B-----FIL1------->---------JNR4 \
    |                                     |     |
    |    Read_sourceTB_Market--\          |     |
    |    Read_sourceTB_Cost------JNR1--\  |     |
    |    Read_sourceTB_A-----------------JNR2   JNR5--->EXP... -->TGT
    |                       |             |     |
    |                       |             |     |
    |                       |             |     |
     ---------------------FIL2->---------JNR3 /
```

How to make a decision for
if A join B `System_Code='University'`failed,  then A join B `System_Code='Policy'`

```
--First joinning condition  
A LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.MEMBERSHIPID = B.MEMBERSHIPID
Where B.System_Code='University'
```

IF <First joinning condition> failed, then execute

```
--Second joinning condition
A LEFT JOIN B ON 
A.address = B.address and A.phonenumber = B.phonenumber

Where B.System_Code='Policy'
```

Comment: Lets say, output of fil1 is called out1,and output of fil2 is called out2. Now, use an iif like this `iif(isnull(out1.col1 ), out2.col1)`. This will make sure to get data from first join and if its null then from second join.

Comment: Hello, I added a sorter right before joiner in each pipeline and sort on the keys, error still exist, the error msg which is ```ERROR: Sorted input joiner [JNR5] cannot have none-pasthrough partitioning type because data reshuffilng will break the sort order.```

Comment: Shouldnt be. But i think some conditions are causing the issue. Can you pls post a screenshot of your mapping? Or at least post the mapping correctly.

Comment: I checked the [sorted input] in the properties tag of Joiner5, the mapping can be run successfully, could you answer this post once again, I want to give you an upvote .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join A with B (twice) based on two different condition and then join them back to one single pipeline for a decision/if-else condition.
Also please note, all your left joins are actually inner join because you are using `B.xxx='something'` condition in the `where` clause.

So, considering above problem -

1. After source qualified of B, add two filters FIL1(system_Code='University') and FIL2(System_Code='Policy') in parallel.
2. Then use JNR1 to join A and B(FIL1) using JOINER on A.MEMBERSHIPID = B_F1.MEMBERSHIPID. Use A as detail table and use 'inner join'.
3. Then join A and B(FIL2)  using JOINER(JNR2) on  A.address = B_F2.address and A.phonenumber = B_F2.phonenumber. Use A as detail table and use 'inner join'.
4. Then join above two pipelines into one single pipeline using another Joiner(JNR3). It should be normal join and join should be primary key from table A. Get all required columns.
5. (EXP)Then use an expression transformation. Use logic similar to below.

```
out_col1 = IIF( isnull(col_tableB_F1_jnr1),col_tableB_F2_jnr2, col_tableB_F1_jnr1)
```

Whole mapping should look like this -

```
SQ_TABLEB --FIL1-> -- JNR1 \
        |               |   |
        |   SQ_TABLEA --|    JNR3-->EXP.... -->TGT  
        |               |   | 
        |--FIL2-> -- JNR2  /
```

But i think your requirement may be like this -

```
A LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.MEMBERSHIPID = B.MEMBERSHIPID AND B.System_Code='University'
```

if yes, then change the `inner join` to `master outer join` in the JNR1 and JNR2.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `B` data source twice, this should be something like:

```
Read_sourceTB_Market--\         
Read_sourceTB_Cost------JNR1--\
Read_sourceTB_A-----------------JNR2-\
Read_sourceTB_B1-----FIL1---->--------JNR4--\
Read_sourceTB_B2-----FIL2---->---------------JNR5--->EXP... -->TGT
```